# Java, Archives, Linux & Cyrillic

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding, tar

I try to write an archiver in java, that creates TAR or ZIP archives, with correctly cyrillic file names, then it opened in linux.
In windows I use org.apache.tools.zip, from ant:

```
ZipOutputStream.setEncoding("cp866");
```

to get it, but file roller (archive manager) in linux don't understand it. In org.apache.tools.tar method setEncoding() isn't exists. Also I try to use some other encoding, that supports Cyrillic, such a cp1251, utf-8, koi-8r but it gaves no result.

Answer (score 1):

Your file may be creating the files correctly and the problem lies on file-roller.
It's known that it can't detect filename's encoding. See [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+question/135192) and [here](http://lists.mandriva.com/bugs/2009-09/msg02284.php).

Attempt to use [unzip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)(filenames will probably be garbled) or [p7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) directly from the shell (there is also a java version - j7zip).

7zip works for me, with utf8 encoding of Cyrillic characters. File roller, Ark, and all others that in fact execute unzip will corrupt the filenames in my system.